# Printing Request debug information on a Java Servlet

Tags: java, python, django, jakarta-ee, servlets

I find it **extremely useful** when doing Django/Python web development to fully inspect a HTTP request like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def index(request):
    logger.info(request)
```

Is there something similar for a Java Servlet?

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // debugInfo should print something similar to what you get in DJANGO
    debugInfo(request);
}
```

Comment: To be sure, it ends up in the std console? (and thus not in the HTTP response, although you didn't pass the `response` through the method)

Comment: It ends up wherever the logger is configured to end. But it doesn't matter. If it generates a string that I could print anywhere else, I will be more than happy.

Comment: Ah right, you're basically looking for a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` implementation which returns a multiline `String` with all the debug information on the `toString()` call? Sorry, none comes to mind.

Comment: As far as I know there is no _built-in_ mechanism to generate a textual representation of all _relevant_ information stored in a given HTTP request. Your `debugInfo` method must assemble a string representation of everything you're interested in. Is this what you need?

Comment: @home: yes. that's what I need. I was looking for something already being done, but I couldn't find it. Will just write one myself and will post an answer about it later.

Comment: @Pablo: This is exactly what I did 100 times :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I got no answers, [I wrote a little helper class](http://blog.roshka.com/2011/07/logging-full-http-requests-in-java.html) to help me with this issue. Hope someone else finds it interesting and useful.

Comment: Your link to the source code for the helper class (http://phoebe.roshka.com/interno/ext/RequestPrinter.java) requires authorization. Can you put it in a gist at github.com instead?

Comment: @Cagatay: I moved the little class to a different place. You can try download it again. Thanks for pointing that out! http://blog.roshka.com/2011/07/logging-full-http-requests-in-java.html

Comment: Lol - I found it useful. An addition to print out particular strings would be welcome (like 'referer').